# Integral identity related with cubic analogue of arithmetic-geometric mean

Tags: integration

This is re-post from [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1190660/integral-identity-related-with-cubic-analogue-of-arithmetic-geometric-mean) as I did not get an answer there.

Let $a,b$ be positive real numbers and we define two sequences $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$ as follows:
$$a_{0}=a,b_{0}=b,a_{n+1}=\frac{a_{n}+2b_{n}}{3},b_{n+1}=\sqrt[3]{\frac{(a_{n}^{2}+a_{n}b_{n}+b_{n}^{2})b_{n}}{3}}\tag{1}$$
Then it is not so difficult to show that both the sequences $\{a_{n}\},\{b_{n}\}$ tend to a common limit which may be denoted by $M_{3}(a,b)$, the cubic arithmetic geometric mean of $a$ and $b$. It also turns out that there is an integral representation of this cubic arithmetic geometric mean. Let us define
$$I(a,b)=\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{t\,dt}{\sqrt[3]{(t^{3}+a^{3})(t^{3}+b^{3})^{2}}}\tag{2}$$ Then we have the relation $$M_{3}(a, b) = \frac{I(1, 1)}{I(a, b)}\tag{3}$$
The above result $(3)$ can be proved easily if we can show that $$I(a_{n},b_{n})=I(a_{n+1},b_{n+1})\tag{4}$$
Given the definition $(2)$ of integral $I(a,b)$ how do I go about proving the identity $(4)$?

Comment: Why are you sure in (3)? Do you have a proof avoiding proving (4)?

Comment: @FedorPetrov: Actually I read the integral relation from http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/organics/vault/comp_aid_analy/paper/html/node5.html But it does not give a proof and throws $(4)$ as a challenge.

Comment: It is not very symmetric. May be, the following holds? $I(a,b,c)=I(\frac{a+b+c}3,\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^2b+b^2c+c^2a}{3}},\sqrt[3]{\frac{ab^2+bc^2+ca^2}{3}})$, where $I(a,b,c)=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{xdx}{\sqrt[3]{(x^3+a^3)(x^3+b^3)(x^3+c^3)}}$? Sorry, Wolframalpha site does not work now, so I am unable to check this numerically.

Comment: @FedorPetrov: You seem to have found the generalization for the identity I am asking in my post. If I put $b = c$ in your relation, I get the same definitions like $(1)$ and $(2)$. So I guess your identity is also correct and if a proof is available it is all the much better.

Comment: The solution is discussed in "Experimentation in Mathematics" by Borwein, Bailey, and Girgensohn (2004, A K Peters), pp265, where the authors give "a variation of [the] ... proof [of John A. Macdonald]" that "consists of a chain of variable substitutions", which is too lengthy to be reproduced by me (Sorry for me being so lazy.). Unfortunately they do not give a reference to that proof of Macdonald. A proof (+ further references) using hypergeometric function identity is given in [this paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1991-323-02/S0002-9947-1991-1010408-0/S0002-9947-1991-1010408-0.pdf).

Comment: .. and I found the above mentioned proof on the web: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.56.7071&rep=rep1&type=pdf.

Comment: @JohannesTrost: Thanks a lot for both the references. On a first look the proofs seem very convoluted and lengthy. I wonder if the substitutions used can be verified by hand calculation. I will try to verify at least some parts.

Comment: Alas, this fails after numerical computations( But maybe some other generalization for three variables a,b,c holds?